# python syntax errorEOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python-3.x, windows

The below is my code and on executing got the error message: `line 1
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal.` 
Help me in identifying the issue.
code is::

```
sessions=os.listdir('\Downloads\Rawdata\')
sessions=sessions[3:]
files=[]
for _ in sessions:
dire=os.listdir('\Downloads\Rawdata\')
for __ in dire:
    files+=os.listdir('Downloads\Rawdata\'+__)
print(files)
```

Comment: Well. I did not check the code myself but it look strange for me in `for __ in dire: files+=os.listdir('Downloads\Rawdata\'+__)`. Can you substitute `__` with some "normal" variable name and try again? E.g. `for e_dir in dire: files+=os.listdir('Downloads\Rawdata\'+e_dir)`

Comment: thank you but i tried it but it again shows the same error in the same line 1

Comment: Hm. Can you check by hand existense of paths: `\Downloads\Rawdata` and `Downloads\Rawdata` ? Which OS are you using? Is it Windows?

Comment: i am using windows 10

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown by unescaped backslashes in your path. If you're lucky, your script may run without any issues but I would prefer to use the raw string literal in this case i.e. the 'r'-prefix before your path string. Also, do take note that you should not end your string with a '\' i.e. before the closing quote.

```
sessions=os.listdir(r'Downloads\Rawdata')
```

I also noticed that your path strings begin with a '\'. If you plan to navigate relative to your root, just define your path without beginning it with a backslash. `r'child_folder\grandchild_folder'`

Further [reading](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Comment: @Anindita Did you apply it to all of your strings with backslashes?

Comment: @Anindita write full directory name starting with drive letter, e.g. `C:\Downloads\Rawdata`

Comment: it does not run in windows but runs in ubuntu. i tried in all these posiible ways in windows but it does not run. is there any other way possible. thank you

Comment: @Anindita I hope the updated answer is clearer now. It should also work on windows